# Where to find old IMAP::Sieve perl module

Tags: perl, imap, perl-module, sieve-language

I am upgrading a server and an existing perl CGI program requires `IMAP::Sieve` perl module.
My problem is that I can't find any reference to it anymore on Internet.
Does someone knows if it has been replaced by something else and/or where I could find it ?

The existing perl CGI program we use is [`websieve`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/websieve/) (can be found on SourceForge).
We do not want to use something else as we customized it and it is working perfectly.
The script is also using `IMAP::Admin`.

Thanks a lot for any hint or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually for old modules the place to go is [backpan](http://backpan.perl.org/), however this looks like it's actually [part of something else](http://www.freshports.org/mail/p5-IMAP-Sieve) and [lives on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/websieve) rather than cpan:

> A Perl module used by websieve for creating Sieve scripts on an Cyrus
>   IMAP mail server.  Sometimes also referenced as 'perlsieve'.
>
> WWW: http://sourceforge.net/projects/websieve

Inside the tarball for the latest release there is a tarball for perlsieve-0.4.9, the make file for which reads:

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
# See lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm for details of how to influence
# the contents of the Makefile that is written.
WriteMakefile(
    'NAME'  => 'IMAP::Sieve',
    'VERSION_FROM' => 'Sieve.pm', # finds $VERSION
);
```

So just install it the old fashioned way:

```
D:\websieve-063a\perlsieve-0.4.9>dmake install
Installing D:\perl\perl\site\lib\IMAP\Sieve.pm
Installing D:\perl\perl\site\lib\IMAP\testssl.pl
Appending installation info to D:\perl\perl\lib/perllocal.pod

D:\websieve-063a\perlsieve-0.4.9>perl Makefile.PL
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for IMAP::Sieve
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

D:\websieve-063a\perlsieve-0.4.9>dmake
Skip blib\lib\IMAP\testssl.pl (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\IMAP\Sieve.pm (unchanged)

D:\websieve-063a\perlsieve-0.4.9>dmake install
Appending installation info to D:\perl\perl\lib/perllocal.pod

D:\websieve-063a\perlsieve-0.4.9>
```

Feel free to `dmake test` before `dmake install`, it prompts for test server criteria, I don't have one.

Comment: Woaw! Thanks a lot for your detailled help. You a are right, this IMAP::Sieve was indeed included in websieve.

The only problem I have with your install procedure is :
Can't use string ("testssl.pl") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/share/perl/5.14/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 1194.
dmake:  Error code 2, while making 'pm_to_blib'

Comment: In fact I just copied Sieve.pm to /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/IMAP/ and it worked immediately (after correcting some minor bug in Sieve.pm)

Comment: @DenisBUCHER Good news, I'm glad this works for you now. The example above is for windows, so using dmake is correct. I've tested using Linux and perl 5.16, using make rather than dmake, and can't reproduce the error you mentioned. I've never used this module or tool so can't vouch for it's quality. Thanks

Comment: I am using it for approximately 60 users, and it works quite well. Very old-fashioned look, and I am only using the away/vacation Sieve filter but it does the job. Good when you have Outlook users on a Linux IMAP server.